# How to show a band structure for water?

Tags: water, reference-request

This question is generated by my attempt to answer [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108980/is-there-any-electronic-component-to-water-conductivity/109272?noredirect=1#comment204049_109272).  I thought I could demonstrate that electronic conduction in water is possible because of the impact of an electric field on the band structure, but I am being hit with comments questioning the existence of band structure in liquids.  I thoughtot was self-evident, but I was asked for references showing water has a band structure and what I am coming up with does not appear to be working (the comments are getting more upvotes than my answer).  So I need help.  Can anybody come up with more clear-cut references demonstrating that water, or liquids generally, has such a band structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do Couto et al have published an article [1] characterizing the density of states (band structure) of water using DFT theory combined with MC sampling. Extrapolating from clusters to bulk water, the HOMO-LUMO gap is 8.55 eV (Table 3).

From the abstract:

> By extrapolating the results for larger clusters the threshold energy
>   for photoelectron emission is $9.6±0.15 eV$ free clusters and
>   $10.58±0.10 eV$ embedded clusters. Our results  for  the  electron 
>   affinity $V_0=−0.17±0.05 eV$ and  adiabatic  band  gap
>   $E_{G,Ad}=6.83±0.05 eV$ of liquid water are in excellent agreement
>   with recent information from theoretical and experimental works.

From the introduction:

> It is generally accepted that water canbe  described  as  a  very 
>   large  band-gap  amorphous semiconductor.11,17 However, it is not
>   obvious that the band-gap of liquid water can be uniquely associated
>   with an optical vertical excitation process, where the gap is
>   defined simply as the highest occupied molecular orbital-lowest
>   unoccupied molecular orbital HOMO-LUMO energy difference. As recently pointed out 
>   by Coeet  al.,3 the reactive nature of electronically excited water
>   molecules,18 the reorganization of water molecules around charged
>   species in liquid phase, and the observed photophysics of anionic
>   defects known as the anion problem 4 strongly indicate that an
>   adiabatic route can be defined for accessing the conduction-band edge
>   in liquid phase. Moreover, given that the time scale ofthe solvent
>   relaxation is much larger than the vertical process, the adiabatic
>   band gap of liquid water cannot be determined vertically.

**Reference**
[1] Cabral do Couto, Estácio, and Costa Cabral J. Chem. Phys.123, 0545102005

Comment: Great, just what I needed!